# sed replacing text in a file

Tags: linux, sed, osx

I would like to replace `<Path_To_BOOST_LIB_DIR>` in a file with the content of `${PREFIX}/lib` but this command

`sed -i .bak 's|<Path_To_BOOST_LIB_DIR>|echo ${PREFIX}/lib|' src/CMakeLists.txt`

produced

`set(BOOST_LIB_DIR echo ${PREFIX}/lib)`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: No shell variables inside single quotes… You can turn them into double quotes but keep in mind that it's still interpreted as it's written in there so you better don't have certain characters in the path name which also have a meaning in a regular expression.